# Merging json encoded arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

Lets say I have these arrays:

```
$array1 = [
  'test' => json_encode([
      'key1' => 'val1',
      'key2' => 'val2',
      'key3' => 'val3'
   ])
]
```

Now I have another array

```
$array2 = [
  'test' => json_encode([
      'key4' => 'val4'
   ])
]
```

After merge I want it to look like :

```
$array3 = [
  'test' => json_encode([
      'key1' => 'val1',
      'key2' => 'val2',
      'key3' => 'val3',
      'key4' => 'val4',
   ])
]
```

But when I do  `$result = array_merge($array1, $array2)`

Then I get this:

```
$array3 = [
  'test' => json_encode([
      'key4' => 'val4'
   ])
]
```

Any suggestions how to fix this? I tried it with `array_merge_recursive` but that also does not give the right result.

Thanks.

Comment: `If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one`

Comment: Merge first the array before encoding it.

Comment: Why are you JSON-encoding a sub-array...?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this to by putting the `test` key in it's own variable.
Then I merged them and json_encoded it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is a bad approach. Ideally, you can first merge and then json encode. Also, all of the arrays has `test` as a key and that is why when you use `array_merge` you are getting the second one only. What you should do is to access to each the subarrays and then merge them. However, here is a piece of code that will output what you need.

```
$array1 = [
  'test' => json_encode([
      'key1' => 'val1',
      'key2' => 'val2',
      'key3' => 'val3'
   ])
];

$array2 = [
  'test' => json_encode([
      'key4' => 'val4'
   ])
];


$array3['test'] = json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($array1['test'], true), json_decode($array2['test'], true)));

var_dump($array3);
```

Comment: Thanks. But lets say I encode it after I merge both arrays. How would that work? B/c That would be the best solution

Comment: That is how it works in the code I sent - 
`$array3['test'] = json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($array1['test'], true), json_decode($array2['test'], true)));`
If you need them encoded, just replace this line with - 
`$array3['test'] = array_merge(json_decode($array1['test'], true), json_decode($array2['test']));`

Answer (score 0):

Merge before json encoding

Try this,

```
$array3 = json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($array1, true),json_decode($array2, true)))
```